# Why does MSDN suggest adding and removing a linked list node to modify its value?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm doing some practice on linked lists and noticed that it suggests removing and adding a node to update its value. [The example below is taken from the MSDN documentation on linked lists:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string[] words = { "the", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "dog" };
LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>(words);
sentence.RemoveLast();
sentence.AddLast("yesterday");
```

Why not just do something like this:

```
sentence.Last.Value = "yesterday"
```

This achieves the same output. Or, if the location of `dog` is unknown:

```
sentence.Find("dog").Value = "yesterday";
```

I can't see what the advantages are to completely removing and then reading the value?

Comment: The snippet `sentence.AddLast("cat");` doesn't appear in the link you posted...? In fact, I can't find `"cat"` anywhere.

Comment: @canton7 - It was modified slightly. Link uses `sentence.AddLast("yesterday");`

Comment: @canton7 Sorry, I changed it slightly and  forgot to put it back...I have modified it back to the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bethink of 2 advantages.

1. When call `RemoveLast` on an empty list, it tells you **The LinkedList is empty.**, if you use `Last.Value`, it will throw `NullReferenceException`, which is less readable.
2. `LinkedListNode` is a class, that means if you have kept a reference of the last node, then change `Last.Value` will also change its value, usually this behaviour is unexpected.

   ```
   var last = sentence.Last;
   ....
   ....
   sentence.Last.Value = "yesterday";
   ```

Comment: Correct, but regarding .2: you would have to be nuts to keep a ref to a LinkedListNode around.

Answer (score 2):

> Why not just do something like this: `sentence.Last.Value = "yesterday";`

Because that particular page wanted to demonstrate Add and Remove logic.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking with my answer... (I'll blame it on it being Monday morning). Your answer is 100% correct. Take an upvote.

Comment: I see. That page said, "`The following code example demonstrates many features of the LinkedList<T> class.`, so I thought that was the suggestion. I can't see anywhere where it says otherwise...ah well. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I skimmed that page for any signs of preferring immutability or so but I didn't see anything special. It's just an arbitrary set of choices.